# Name of the preamble for a for-loop?

Tags: loops, for-loop, language-agnostic, terminology

Is there a name for the preamble of a for-loop containing the initialisation, condition and afterthought expressions?

```
for(init; condition; after) // What is the name for this preamble?
{
}
```

Comment: For Loop Control Statement.

Comment: The code `for(init; condition; after)` is not a statement in JavaScript. Although  `for(init; condition; after) {}` is (AFAICT). Does this mean that the name of the preamble might depend on the language?

Comment: I think this question would fit better if it wasn't JS-specific. At least all C-like languages will share the terminology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the statement (or block) inside the loop is called the *loop body*, the "preamble" would be called the *loop head* or *header*.

Answer (score 2):

*Note*: This answer was written when the question was originally targetting JavaScript

---

Strictly speaking, no, there is no name for this as far as [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.3) is concerned:

> 12.6.3 The for Statement
>
> The production
>
> *IterationStatement* **: for (** *ExpressionNoIn<sub>opt</sub>* **;** *Expression<sub>opt</sub>* **;** *Expression<sub>opt</sub>* **)** *Statement* ...

IE it's defined purely as a series of tokens (`for`, `(`, `;`, `;` and `)`) with three optional expressions also.

Any names you may see for this will be what other people have concocted, and are not *formal* names.

---

Having looked at the C# spec as well now after the question edit, it's much the same as JavaScript where a `for` loop is defined as a series of tokens with expressions with no specific name given to the entirety of this section.

The inner parts in both are either just defined as "statement" or "embedded-statement", but since we commonly refer to those as the *body*, I think [Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33672039/791010) is probably reasonable.